# How can I get information from a list inside json using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following C# class:

```
public class JsonBackup
{
    public int Added { set; get; }
    public int DEVCount { set; get; }
    public int DS1Count { set; get; }
    public IList<ViewEvent> Events { get; set; }
}
```

and this is used to return a Json string like this:

```
return Json(new JsonBackup
            {
                Added = added,
                DEVCount = devCount,
                DS1Count = ds1Count,
                Events = t.Events
            });
```

I have the following javascript call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('data-href'),
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST'
    })
        .done(function (data) {
            backupDone(data, ajaxElapsed);
        })
```

I know that I can get the data.Added etc properties but how can I get the Event information that's 
part of the Events list?

Here's an example of the C# class that has the event data:

```
public class ViewEvent {
    public long Elapsed { get; private set; }
    public ET EventType { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public string Message { get; private set; }
    public int Quantity { get; private set; }
}
```

What I really need is some JQuery or javascript way to get the following information out of what is returned from the Ajax call and add it to the ul element with the id="stats"

```
<li>@viewEvent.Description : @viewEvent.Elapsed ms</li>
```

Comment: You know javascript works on the client side and C# on the server, right?

Comment: Please show the example output for the JSON.

Comment: I am not sure how I can get the example output to show you. I can see it in the browser when I hover over it and debug it.  I know how jQuery works on the client and C# on the server. But just don't know how exactly to get things from a list inside json.

Comment: @Marilou Use this `.done(function(data) { console.log(data); });` and give us the output from the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you need in your done function would look something like this:

```
$.each(data.Events, function (i, item) {
    $('ul#stats').append('<li>' + item.Description + ' : ' + item.Elapsed + ' ms</li>');
});
```